# Error hosting OWIN server in managed assembly called from unmanaged C++

Tags: .net, owin, managed-c++

I am trying to host an OWIN server instance inside of a managed .NET assembly that I call from an unmanaged executable.  I currently have it working inside the unmanaged code using C++/CLI just fine.  However in an attempt to clean up the code and move the OWIN startup to a managed .NET client library, whenever I attempt to start the OWIN server inside the .NET assembly I get the following runtime error from my unmanaged application:

"Runtime error!  R6034 An application has made an attempt to load the C runtime library incorrectly."

Some looking around seems to indicate this error is caused by not having a manifest file.  However I'm not entirely sure if this means modifying our unmanaged code's manifest or embedding one in the .NET assembly (I've tried both without much luck).  I'm also not exactly sure why just moving the OWIN startup to an assembly would require a manifest when it worked when I was starting it inside my unmanaged C++/CLI code.

What is the best way to troubleshoot/solve this problem?